# How to render the same component but with initial state (conditionally)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have one specific component **that manages its own state using `useState`.**
The problem is that I want to render conditionally the same component:

```
const PaymentScannerView: React.FC<Props> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return props.onFront ? (
    <PBScanner
      header={t('paymentScanner.front.capture.header')}
      instruction={t('paymentScanner.front.capture.instruction')}
      reCaptureText={t('paymentScanner.front.confirmation.reCaptureText')}
      continueText={t('paymentScanner.front.confirmation.continueText')}
      confirmCaptureHandler={props.confirmFrontCaptureHanlder}
      reCaptureHandler={props.reCaptureFrontHandler}
    />
  ): (
    <PBScanner
      header={t('paymentScanner.back.capture.header')}
      instruction={t('paymentScanner.back.capture.instruction')}
      reCaptureText={t('paymentScanner.back.confirmation.reCaptureText')}
      continueText={t('paymentScanner.back.confirmation.continueText')}
      confirmCaptureHandler={props.confirmBackCaptureHandler}
      reCaptureHandler={props.reCaptureBackHandler}
    />
  );
};
```

But I don't want to share this state between those 2 "versions".
To clarify it, suppose this `PBScanner` component has internal state of counting from `0`. Then is it renders for 5 times within the first condition (meaning that `props.onFront` is true 5 times), then, even if suddenly `props.onFront` would equal to `false` then the second version would preserve the state and would be rendered with counter equal to `5`.

That's not what I want. I want to "treat" these two components as they won't share the state.

How can I do it?

Comment: Add a props hidden in your PBScanner that will hide your component if it's true so you can have two instance of your PBScanner inside PaymentScannerView and keep your internal state clean

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you actually want.

1. If the state should be **maintained** in both components individually, then you should render them both. The component itself should then decide if it will return anything. (Per @NicolasMenettrier suggestion).
2. If you want them to lose their state, when `props.onFront` changes, then the simplest solution is to add a key-property. E.g.:

   ```
   <PBScanner key="front" .../> // and "back" respectively
   ```

   This way react will regard both as distinct, giving them their own state.
   *Note* though that this will make them lose their state **everytime** `props.onFront` changes.

Answer (score 0):

as They said previously, it depends on what you want.
in my opinion the simple solution would be to add **key** property to **PBScanner**.

an other solution is to add **useEffect** hook in **PBScanner ** like this :

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'; 
...
export default PBScanner({header, ...}) {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
UseEffect(() => {
setCount(0); // each time PBScanner update with change in header
// (instruction...), Count go to 0.
}, [header]);//here you can use header or instruction ...

}
```